# Lower Case Snippets in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I tend to write most code in lower case.  With SQL Server, when you use a snippet created in SQL Server Management Studio, it is always in upper case, like these examples:

[image]

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[uuid]
      ,[componentNumber]
      ,[xmlPath]
      ,[xmlContent]
      ,[ingestDate]
      ,[modifiedDate]
FROM [dbo].[DRMC]
```

I am aware of `upper()` and `lower()` functions in T-SQL. The question is in reference to SSMS. Is there a way to change SSMS to use lower case instead?

Comment: just realized that this should prob be on https://dba.stackexchange.com.  it's ok to comment like that.  i wouldnt be offended.

Comment: anyone know how i can request a moderator to migrate this to Stack Exchange?

Comment: I have mark this question for other site. (DBA Stack). However, it will require two more votes.

Comment: https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-refactor.aspx - SQL formatter SSMS Plugin/
Tab capitalization: https://sql-formatter.online/options/capitalization